# App crashes, if I access a method in my custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I created in Android Studio a custom view template and a custom view, which inherit from the template. If I access a method in the custom view, the whole app crashes with this error message in Logcat:

```
2020-11-01 13:53:22.790 587-587/de.rescuemod E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.rescuemod, PID: 587
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.rescuemod/de.rescuemod.formulars.bike.FormBikeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.rescuemod.customElements.MonoEditText.setText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.rescuemod.customElements.MonoEditText.setText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at de.rescuemod.formulars.bike.FormBikeActivity.readDatabase(FormBikeActivity.kt:653)
    at de.rescuemod.formulars.bike.FormBikeActivity.onCreate(FormBikeActivity.kt:598)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

2020-11-01 13:53:22.824 587-587/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 587 SIG: 9

Here is my parent custom view template:

```
open class CustomElementTemplate(context : Context, attrs : AttributeSet) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

/* -------------------- Member variables -------------------- */

/** Main linear layout */
val llMain = LinearLayout(context)

/** Title textview */
val txtTitle = TextView(context)

/** Getting the density of the view */
val density = context.displayMetrics.density.toInt()


/* -------------------- Initialization -------------------- */

/**
 * Primary Constructor
 */
init {

    //Constraint layout
    this.id = R.id.cl_customelementtemplate
    setPadding(8 * density, 0, 8 * density, 0)
    background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.border_padding, null)
    layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)



    //Title of the view
    txtTitle.id = R.id.txt_title
    val lpTitle = LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    txtTitle.setBackgroundColor(if (getDarkMode(context)) {
        resources.getColor(R.color.backgroundAccent_dark, null)
    } else {
        resources.getColor(R.color.backgroundAccent_light, null)
    })

    txtTitle.layoutParams = lpTitle
    txtTitle.setPadding(5 * density, 0, 5 * density, 0)
    txtTitle.textSize = 15f
    txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8A8A8A"))
    txtTitle.visibility = View.GONE
    addView(txtTitle)



    //Main LinearLayout
    llMain.id = R.id.ll_main
    llMain.minimumHeight = 30 * density
    llMain.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    llMain.layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    llMain.setPadding(8 * density, 20 * density, 8 * density, 14 * density)
    addView(llMain)
}


/* -------------------- Lifecycle -------------------- */

/**
 * After the layout was completly loaded in the view, execute the code here
 */
override fun onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate()

    //Setting margins
    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(this)
    constraintSet.connect(txtTitle.id, ConstraintSet.START, this.id, ConstraintSet.START,5 * density)
    constraintSet.connect(txtTitle.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, this.id, ConstraintSet.TOP,0)
    constraintSet.applyTo(this)
}
}
```

The custom view:

```
class MonoEditText(context: Context, attrs : AttributeSet) : CustomElementTemplate(context, attrs) {

/* -------------------- Member variables -------------------- */

/** EditText element */
private var etxt = EditText(context)



/* -------------------- Initialization -------------------- */

/**
 * Primary Constructor
 */
init {

    //Collect the values from XML
    context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MonoEditText, 0, 0).apply {

        //EditText / AutocompleteText
        if(getBoolean(R.styleable.MonoEditText_autoComplete, false)) {
            etxt = AutoCompleteTextView(context)
        }

        etxt.id = R.id.etxt_main
        etxt.layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 60 * density)
        llMain.minimumHeight = 30 * density

        llMain.addView(etxt)



        //Fill all kind of textes like titles, subtitles, etc.
        try {
            if(getString(R.styleable.MonoEditText_title)?.isNotEmpty()!!) {
                setTitle(getString(R.styleable.MonoEditText_title)!!)
            }
        } catch ( e: Exception) {}




        //InputType
        when(getString(R.styleable.MonoEditText_inputType)) {
            "0" -> etxt.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED or InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
            "1" -> etxt.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            "2" -> etxt.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            "3" -> etxt.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
            "4" -> etxt.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS
            "5" -> etxt.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS
        }
        
    }
}




/* -------------------- Getter/Setter Methods -------------------- */

/**
 * Set the selected value by string
 * @param   value    String which should be choosen
 */
fun setText(value : String) {
    //etxt.setText(value)
}
}
```

I adding the custom view in the xml activity like this:

```
<de.rescuemod.customElements.MonoEditText
    android:id="@+id/etxt_LGEW"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:inputType="number"
    app:title="@string/LGEW" />
```

And in the activity, I put a value in the editText field:

```
class FormularActivity : FormularTemplate() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //Connection to the XML-Layout-File
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_bike)

    ...
    etxt_LGEW.setText("Leergewicht")
    ...
}
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: In your final code snippet, `etxt_LGEW` is `null`.

Comment: Ok, and what can I do against? For every custom view which I want to add a "findviewbyId" and storing the result in a variable? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: You could use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), `findViewById()`, or similar solutions. This has nothing to do with the fact that this is a custom view.

Comment: In an early version, I used in the custom view a XML, which I added to the class with "View.inflate()" and it worked. But I want to write that completely programmatically and since then, it doesn't work anymore. And I need to use the custom view 50-100 times per activity, so, I need a smarter way than I add to every custom view a "findviewbyId" ;)

Comment: If you don't use what CommonsWare suggested, you'll always end up with an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it has anything to do with the class itself, but something in the code of your Activity:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.rescuemod.customElements.MonoEditText.setText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at de.rescuemod.formulars.bike.FormBikeActivity.readDatabase(FormBikeActivity.kt:653)
```

Looking at this stack trace it looks like the issue is in your readDatabase function in FormBikeActivity. It says that calling setText from that function causes the NPE. We might need some code from that function, and the place where it is called from in onCreate with some context to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Yeah it's saying that at line 653 of ``FormBikeActivity`` you're calling ``setText`` on a ``MonoEditText`` variable that's null